# Enable scrolling inside a data-spy "affix"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got an affixed data-spy side-menu div that has too many elements to fit in my browser window. The side-menu contains links that anchor to other areas in the same page.

Currently, the div is affixed to the page just fine, but since there are too many elements I can only navigate to about half the links in the menu. This is bad because I want to be able to easily go from item to item no matter where I'm at in the page - the page is very long.

If I add `style="overflow:scroll;"`, a scrollbar appears in the affixed div, but the scroll is grayed out and it won't actually scroll.

How can I make the affixed div scrollable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add *height* property to your div.

Comment: ok, overlow: auto is not working in your case, have you trie to add height for element?

Comment: Do you mind explaining why adding the height property fixed this?

Comment: Div has default "height" value as "auto", auto means that div will scale according to content -> no scroll need. With some "height" value scrolling should appear when content has overflow.

Comment: @alexey in this case scroll bar is visible always. is there any way to make scrollbar visible only when needed

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me (and what I copied from Bootstrap's documentation page...)

```
height: max-height: calc(100vh - 4rem);
overflow-y: auto;
```

Now the scrollbar appears only when needed (viewport height is insufficient for the content). Seems to work nicely at first glance...

See also: [How to add auto scroll bar vertically to cssbootstrap affix menu for smaller screens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41472445/how-to-add-auto-scroll-bar-vertically-to-cssbootstrap-affix-menu-for-smaller-scr)